# Website Deployment and IIS Setup

Tags: asp.net, iis

What's the standard or common practice to setup the local path of a website in IIS.  Is it c:/inetput/MYWEBSITE  or c:/inetpub/wwwroot/MYWEBSITE?

According to this article you can go either way. [Should I put my ASP.NET websites in the wwwroot folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529913/should-i-put-my-asp-net-websites-in-the-wwwroot-folder)

Thx for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `wwwroot` folder under Intepub. The path may looks like `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`

But you don't need to put under Intetpub to make your site work. you can put in any other folder also and just map the location to that folder in your website settings under IIS.

[image]

It is just personal choice. Both places works. I personally keep it under another folder because sometimes i forget to take backup of my inetpub.

Comment: Correct. Just wondering what everybody frequently choose to setup the IIS local path on an asp.net website.