# Publishing ASP.NET for use locally, without IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application that works perfectly fine using IIS. However, I have a user that wants a local version of the application to run right from their desktop. The application doesn't connect to external networks so that's not an issue. I just want to know if/how I can setup a local version of an ASP.NET application to run right of a users desktop? I was thinking it would be like running on IIS Express.

Thanks

Comment: Not being funny at all, but did you try searching for standalone .Net web servers?  Alternatively, if you can build the application as a dotnet core application then you can just copy the bin folder for them.

Comment: I've never needed one for ASP.Net myself - only the other side of the fence (PHP).

Comment: @Archer is there a simple way to convert an ASP.NET application to dotnet core?

Comment: I don't know.  I've used dotnet core very little as it's still quite young and I only work on software that requires as much stability as you can get.  Again, just search - you're not the first person to want help with these things.

Comment: Is the user on windows? If so, you can use the old and good IIS.

Comment: I was thinking about using IIS, but their ip address will be constantly changing and it's a but of work to set it up, any alternatives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure IIS 7 for localhost website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777026/how-to-configure-iis-7-for-localhost-website)